# changing View from UIWindow class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

I would like to know how can i change the view from a UIWindow class..for example, My app has a countdown timer view, when a user starts the timer, they can switch to other screen and the timer runs in the statusbar, what i want is when the user taps on the status bar (i have a custom button on the top of the status bar), it fires this method and change the view from current view to timer's view...

```
- (void)statusbarButtonTouched
{

    NSLog(@"Button TOuched");

    [self addSubview:??]

}
```

Comment: You mean you want to add a view on window, so that you can bring it front in entire application where ever you want right?

Comment: yes... i need the current view (whatever it is) to remove and get the timerView on top.

Comment: I don't think you need to remove the current view just add your view on window when ever you want to show it and remove afterwards.

Comment: can you please share a sample code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `timerView` in App delegate with defined property:

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *timerView;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[FLViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FLViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    self.timerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.frame];
    [self.timerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [self.window addSubview:self.timerView];
    [self.timerView setHidden:YES];


    return YES;
}
```

**Code to bring this view on front:**

```
- (IBAction)shouTimerViewTouched:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [delegate.timerView setHidden:NO];
    [delegate.window bringSubviewToFront:delegate.timerView];
}
```

That's it. You can pull for running demo from here https://github.com/rptwsthi/TrickTest.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

as per docs

```
- (void)removeFromSuperview
```

> Unlinks the receiver from its superview and its window, and removes it
>   from the responder chain.